# Uploading maven artifacts to Nexus 3.13.0 very slow and fails occassionally

Tags: maven, containers, blobstore, nexus3

I have a nexus3 oss (3.13.0) docker container deployed in aws backed with a s3 blobstore. Our ci jobs are continuously uploading artifacts to this repo and worked just fine. However, off late uploading maven artifacts takes a long time and in some cases eventually fails.

It was originally version 3.12.0 and thought upgrading version might help, but it didn't. Also checked if it has anything to do with connectivity or permissions to s3 and found nothing.

**Update:**
Switched to a file based blobstore and the issue still persists, so we can at least rule out that it's not specific to s3 blobstore.

The repo size is greater than 20GB so increased the heap allocation as recommended [in the documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-requirements#SystemRequirements-Memory), but still did not help.

Any idea what might be happening?

Here's what I see in the logs on nexus3:

```
org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreException: BlobId: null, Error uploading blob
    at org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.s3.internal.MultipartUploader.upload(MultipartUploader.java:98)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.s3.internal.S3BlobStore.lambda$0(S3BlobStore.java:220)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.s3.internal.S3BlobStore.create(S3BlobStore.java:257)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.s3.internal.S3BlobStore.create(S3BlobStore.java:217)
    ...
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.getError(HttpInput.java:1138)
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you find an answer for your problem?

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I have very slow uploads too in the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the right order of realms in the admin section. In my case the ldap realm was ordered before the local authentication and local authorizing realms, but users were actually connecting using a locally created user. So it would try to do a ldap lookup before a local lookup which was causing the delay in the authentication mechanism. Once the order was changed to move the local realms above the ldap realm, things got better and uploads were much faster.